# How to disable flag in "ngx-intl-tel-input" lib?

Tags: angular7, flags

how to disable flag in "ngx-intl-tel-input" lib, I disable input field in form has ngx-intl-tel-input but not disable flag.
Please see issue fixed "https://github.com/webcat12345/ngx-intl-tel-input/issues/205"

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in the latest releases. To disable your control, including the country dropdown:

```js
phoneForm = new FormGroup({
   phone: new FormControl({
    value: undefined,
    disabled: true
  }, [Validators.required])
});
```

or

```js
this.phoneForm.controls['phone'].disable();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a hack. Take a ref of `<ngx-mat-intl-tel-input>` and disable the button inside it. Check the code below.

HTML:

```
<ngx-mat-intl-tel-input
    [preferredCountries]="['us']"
    [enablePlaceholder]="true"
    [enableSearch]="true"
    format="national"
    name="phone"
    placeholder="Phone Number"
    formControlName="phone"
    #phoneField
  ></ngx-mat-intl-tel-input>
```

Component TS:

```
 @ViewChild('phoneField')
  public phoneField;

public ngAfterViewChecked() {
    // disabling country selection button
      try {
        this.phoneField.elRef.nativeElement.firstChild.children[0].disabled = 'true';
      } catch (e) {
        // ignore this
      }
  }
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the disabled property and add [disabled]="true"